# What is a good design to update the view's frame whenever it's subviews frame is updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a custom view which has subviews. I want the view's frame width to be same as its combined subview's width. The width is not known when the view is initialized.

The subview's frame is updated as needed by calling setNeedslayout whenever data changes, which would in turn call layoutSubviews. But triggering the update in the opposite direction (from subView to view) is not working for me. 
I tried overriding sizeThatFits in the custom view to return the updated width based on its children but it only works when the first time the subviews width is set. After that even if it does return the correct size, the view's frame is not updated

I also tried calling setFrame on the customview which also doesn't work.

I added an observer on the frame property of subView and on the frame change notification, called setFrame on the view itself which also did not cause it to be redrawn.

What would be the right way to achieve this to force the view's frame to be updated and redrawn based on its subviews?

Comment: So in the paragraph two idea you had the subview calling something like `[[self superview] setNeedsLayout]`? If so is there anything special about the views that might affect the overall hierarchy, e.g. is the parent a `UITableViewCell`? I'm clutching at straws.

Comment: The subview consists of an ActivutyIndicator and UILabel. The mainview listens for notifications when the label text should be updated and after updating the label, calls [self setNeedsLayout]. No the mainview is not a UItableViewCell. I notice first time the text is set, the views frame is correct. Lets say now the label text is shorter. I would want the views frame to shrink but doesn't happen.